# Add new object to local json file in Angular 4

Tags: json, angular

I have a simple method to call the json file located in my assets folder

```
    private jsonPath = '../assets/data/sample.json';
    constructor(private http: Http) { 
    http.get(this.jsonPath)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.posts = response.json();
    })
```

Works well on reading it however I want to perform CRUD operation on it (for example create a new object). Is it possible to do?

Comment: You cannot it is meant to be a server side thing Angular cannot help in this

Comment: You need a real API, or at least Angular's own in-memory API (https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api - but that isn't designed for production use). Editing a JSON file on the front end server is not a good move.